# Tika Parsing special Characters to plain text

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I am trying to convert a doc format to plain text following the apache tika example, however I am having trouble with apostrophes and Bullet points, is it possible to specify how to handle such characters?

```
public String parseToPlainText() throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

    InputStream stream = ContentHandlerExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.doc");
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    try {
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
        return handler.toString();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: What sort of trouble? And are you sure the problem isn't coming from when you print/write the text out after Tika is completed?

Comment: Those characters appear as ? Or [] , I thought they would be parsed

Comment: Where are they appearing as that? And are you sure that the problem really isn't how you're printing them out?